# checking the equality of variances when we have very small data sets

Tags: variance, small-sample

I have two groups with very small sample sizes. Each group has around 6 observations. I was wondering which test I can use in order to check the quality of variances? Is there any cutoff value in order to compare the variances?

Comment: What do you mean by "quality of variances"? Is there an missing e?

Comment: @user3139228's answer seems like a good start.  Can you say more about *why* you are comparing/testing equality of variance between the groups?

Comment: @ Ben Bolker, thanks for the comment, I want to check the equality of means but first I need to see whether the variances are equal or not. As we have very small sample sizes, is there any cut-off point in order to compare the variances? Forexample if the ratio of variances is more than this cutoff then I could say that the can not be equal.

Answer (score 1):

> I have two groups with very small sample sizes. Each group has around
>   6 observations.

It means that you have a very small [statistical power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(statistics)). Your null hypothesis says that both variances are equal. And you have quite a small probability to reject it in favor of an alternative hypothesis even if the null hypothesis is false.

> I was wondering which test I can use in order to check the quality of variances?

I think there is no any magic bullet for your problem except trying to increase the number of observations.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Is there any cutoff for comparing the variances? (Forexample) if the ratio of variances is more than 2 then I could say that the variances are not the same.

Comment: The cutoff inversely depends on the number of observations (degrees of freedom) you have.